# Laravel 4 - Writing query using case

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to write the following query using L4's query builder.

```
SELECT u.user_id,c.c_id,u.username,u.email
 FROM conversation c, users u
 WHERE CASE 
 WHEN c.user_one = '$user_one'
 THEN c.user_two = u.user_id
 WHEN u.user_two = '$user_one'
 THEN c.user_one= u.user_id
 END 
 AND (
 c.user_one ='$user_one'
 OR c.user_two ='$user_one'
 )
 Order by c.c_id DESC
```

I cant seem to find anything in the L4 doc's about CASE

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 4 does not have support for this using the `Query Builder`. However you can use the general `select` function as such

```
$params = array($user_one, $user_one, $user_one, $user_one);
$results = DB::select(
    "SELECT u.user_id, c.c_id, u.username, u.email
    FROM conversation c, users u
    WHERE 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.user_one = ?
            THEN c.user_two = u.user_id
            WHEN u.user_two = ?
            THEN c.user_one = u.user_id
        END 
        AND (
            c.user_one = ?
            OR c.user_two = ?
        )
    ORDER BY c.c_id DESC",
    $params
);
```

You can read more about this on Laravels [database documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/database).