# what is the equivelent orderby case query in laravel?

Tags: laravel

What is the equivalent query of this in **Laravel 5.4**

```
select id,name
from friends
order by case when id in (5,15,25) then -1 else id end,id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Controller namespace
use DB;
use App\Friend;

//In controller method    
$friends = Friend::select('id', 'name')
               ->orderBy(DB::raw('case when id in (5,15,25) then -1 else id end,id'))
               ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw() to make a raw SQL query, instead of using Eloquent's query builder. [Here is the documentation for it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions).

If it helps, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131046/laravel-4-writing-query-using-case) is a similar question asked in Laravel 4; old but still relevant.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

If you want to use Laravel Query Builder:

```
$result = DB::select('
    select id, name
    from friends
    order by case when id in (5,15,25) then -1 else id end, id
');
```

If you want to use Laravel Eloquent, in conjunction with Query Builder:

```
$result = \App\Friend::select('id', 'name')
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('case when id in (5,15,25) then -1 else id end'), 'id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `raw` *portion* of the query instead of building the whole thing like that. So doing:

```
DB::table('your_table')
    ->orderBy(
        DB::raw('case when id in (5,15,25) then -1 else id end,id')
    )->get()
```

Will return first the records with an id of 5,15 and 25 (if they exists), then the rest ordered by id. Not sure if it's what you were after.